# how parse dynamic data through routing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to achieve list a page and detail page using feeds i gathered from various sourcess using the google feed api,

```
<div class="post" ng-repeat="feed in feeds | orderBy:'title'">
<div class="col col-50" ng-repeat="item in feed.entries">
  <div href class="accent">
     <img style="max-width:100%;height:auto;" src="    {{item.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url}}" alt="">

    <h4><a href="#/home/detail/{{feed}}/{{item}}"> //here href on a h4 tag to route with params 
    {{item.title}}</a></h4>

    <h4><small>{{item.author}}</small></h4>
    <p>{{item.contentSnippet}}</p>
  </div></div></div>
```

he idea is feed[index].entries[index].title ,so parsing the feed in feeds as index and item in feed.entries as the second index , but it give me nothing ,any work around

Comment: Did you check the value of feeds in your controller ? What did you get ?

Comment: i can get the data ,it return a feeds object with all the data, am persistening it on all controllers , including the detail page controller . feeds[index].entries[index]. give me access one one rssfeed site first and next index get specific entry /article in the list item in the site ,so i want to route the to details page + firstindex / secondindex